# Ubuntu 20.04 hangs frequently

Tags: 20.04

Just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a new computer (Ryzen 7 5800H, 16GB, RTX 3050 Ti) alongside Windows 10 and it's hanging very frequently after startup - this started from the very beginning. It's usually only a few minutes and doesn't correlate with anything in particular as far as I can tell. After it hangs, very few things work, although SysRq codes appear to still work. It's definitely not a memory issue (it's only using a couple GB when it hangs), and I usually haven't had time to open anything except a terminal by the time it hangs - nothing resource intensive. I looked briefly at dmesg and syslog and there didn't appear to be anything out of the ordinary. I'm suspicious of the GPU drivers, since some other similar questions had problems with that, but I'm not sure what fixing that would entail.

Comment: Are you using the Nvidia proprietary drivers? You are if you selected that option during the OS installation or installed them after. If so, which version? Next question, have you disabled Secure Boot?

Comment: I believe I did, `nvidia-smi` tells me it's version `470.103.01`. I've already tried disabling Secure Boot and the problem persisted.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so it turned out it was a graphics driver issue (as far as I can tell). Just running `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` appeared to fix the problem.